# one to one relationship with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to create a one to one relationship between two tables.

One of them is Person:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private long id;
private String _email;
    private String _pass;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

public String getEmail() {
        return _email;
    }


    public void set_email(String _email) {
        this._email = _email;
    }


    public String getPass() {
        return _pass;
    }


    public void set_pass(String _pass) {
        this._pass = _pass;
    }
}
```

and the second is ReqC2dmRegId table:

```
public class ReqC2dmRegId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Person person;
String C2dmid; 
private long id;

public ReqC2dmRegId(){}

public String getC2dmid() {
    return C2dmid;
}


public void setC2dmid(String c2dmid) {
    C2dmid = c2dmid;
}

public ReqC2dmRegId(Person person, String C2dmid) {
    super();
    this.person = person;
    this.C2dmid = C2dmid;
}


public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}


public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Now, in my program, I always create the `Person` first and only when I need I add this `ReqC2dmRegId`.

Now, what I try to do is to link this two tables. I mean, when I persist this `ReqC2dmRegId` (of course I add to the person in `ReqC2dmRegId` the right id) I want my `ReqC2dmRegId` to **update or save** a new row with the right `Person` id.

These are my hbm files:

ReqC2dmRegId.hbm.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 26, 2012 11:29:57 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="c2dm.ReqC2dmRegId" table="REQC2DMREGID">
        <id name="id" type="long">
         <generator class="foreign">
           <param name="property">person</param>
           </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="person" class="Entities.Person" cascade="all" />


        <property name="C2dmid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="C2DMID" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Person.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 26, 2012 11:29:57 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entities.Person" table="PERSON">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="_email" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="_EMAIL" />
        </property>
        <property name="_pass" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="_PASS" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I try to run:

```
//this should to update or save the object in DB
       public void update (Object query){ 
                    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                    em.getTransaction().begin();
                    //em.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();
                    em.merge(query);
                    em.flush();
                    em.getTransaction().commit();
                    em.close();


                }
```

I get :

```
attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property:Person
```

In the end, it should look like this:

Person

```
**id     email              _pass**
2      lala@gmail.com     1234
```

ReqC2dmRegId

```
**id     REQC2DMREGID**
2      ffgghhjj
```

**Update:**
after i gave up try to understand way it's not working
i change my ReqC2dmRegId.hbm.xml
to look like this (many-to-one):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> <!-- Generated Mar 27, 2012 9:58:08 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 --> <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="c2dm.ReqC2dmRegId" table="REQC2DMREGID">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="person" class="Entities.Person" fetch="join" unique="true" cascade="save-update"  not-null="true"  >
            <column name="PERSON" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="C2dmid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="C2DMID" />
        </property>
    </class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is working fine the problem is when i try to modify ReqC2dmRegId table 
with my update method it create a now row with the same personid

```
id    person_id  C2dmid
1      3          asd123
2      3          dfvghj
```

way it's not update the right row instated create a new one and although i make the "many to one" property to be  unique="true"?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you use Annotations instead of XML file? I find Annotations easy and more intuitive

Comment: At the beginning i found xml is more easy for me for some reason.. and i start work with them and now it's too hard to change all my objects..

Answer (score 0):

You have to be clear about the kind of relation: Is one-to-one or many-to-one?
Look like is a many-to-one unidirectional relation.

Here is an example with Annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;
  private String _email;
  private String _pass;

  //getters and setters
}
```

And the other class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ReqC2dmRegId")
public class ReqC2dmRegId {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
private Person person;

//getters and setters

}
```